# Composer error "TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyNames called on non-object"

Tags: cloudify

When trying to get started with Cloudify, importing the "Cloudify Hello World Example", I get an error:

> TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyNames called on non-object

I get the same error for any blueprint I try to import. I've searched, but found no help on this error.

The example is being imported from a local clone of cloudify-hello-world-example.git on GitHub. I'm using the Composer UI "Blueprint Settings" tool "Import" option, and selecting the local file "blueprint.yaml" from the cloned repo.

I'm running this on CentOS 7, and installed the Composer as described at thank_you_composer.htm on getcloudify.org. Logging into the Composer at localhost port 3000, using Chrome or Firefox, same result.

What is the reason for this `TypeError` when importing Cloudify blueprints, and how do I correct/avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

The composer philosophy is to model and design applications.

You can use it to create new blueprints and add new stencils.

For the moment (version 3.3.1) there is a problem importing blueprints that are using external imports (https://cloudifysource.atlassian.net/browse/CFY-4325), you can bypass it by importing the blueprint without those plugins and then add lifecycle operations that will add the functions of those plugins.

Comment: Does "for the moment" mean that this is a bug/feature in development? If so, please  point to the bug report / Jira issue related to this so that I can track the progress. Also in the meantime I suggest that the import function be grayed out or a disclaimer given to the user about the limitation. It's pretty fundamental as nearly all blueprints will reference imports, and thus this issue significantly limits the utility of the Composer.

Comment: You are right and the answer was edited to include all relevant data. You can still import blueprints, so there is no point disabling this feature. The bug will be solved soon enough and you will be able to import all blueprints.